# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, destroy

I'm getting this really weird error when I submit my nested form.

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _destroy`

Any idea why this may be? It's a bit of a concern as I'm having to remove the 'destroy' hidden_field with javascript temporarily until i figure out what it is, meaning i can't delete anything!

_*form.html.erb*

```
<%= nested_form_for(@post, :html=> {:multipart => true, :class=> "new_blog_post", :id=> "new_blog_post"}) do |f| %>

 <%= field do %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Give your post a title", :class=>"span12" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= field do %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Write something here...", :id=>"blog-text", :class=>"span12" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= f.label :search_locations, "Add locations to your post" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name,"",:class=>"localename", :id=>"appendedInput", :placeholder=> "Name of the location", :autocomplete => "off" %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add a location", :locations %>

 <%= actions do %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", :class=>"btn", :disable_with => 'Uploading Image...' %>

<% end end%>
```

_posts_controller.rb_

```
class PostsController < ::Blogit::ApplicationController   

...   

def new
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])
  @location = @post.locations.build

end



def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  #@post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id]) removed so any use can edit any post
  @location = @post.locations.build
end



def create
   location_set = params[:post].delete(:locations_attributes) unless params[:post][:locations_attributes].blank?

   @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])

   @post.locations = Location.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set) unless location_set.nil?


 if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end


def update
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully updated.'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_url, notice: "Blog post was successfully destroyed."
end
```

*location.rb*

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save { |location| location.destroy if location.name.blank? }

  has_many :location_post
  has_many :posts, :through => :location_post
  has_many :assets

   attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude, :name, :post_id, :notes, :asset, :assets_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers


  def self.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set)
   locations = []
   locations = locations.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }
   location_set.each do |key, location|

    locations << find_or_initialize_by_name(location)
  end
     locations
  end

 end
```

EDIT:

*Snippet of rendered form in new.html.erb*

```
    <div class="row span locsearch">      
       <div class="input-append span3">

        <input autocomplete="off" class="localename" id="appendedInput" name="name" placeholder="Name of the location" type="text" value="">


        <span class="add-on"><input id="post_locations_attributes_0__destroy" name="post[locations_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_nested_fields" data-association="locations"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></span>  </div>

<div class="latlong offset3 span4"> <p class="help-block">Enter the name of the town or city visited in this blog entry.</p>
        </div>

        <input class="LegNm" id="post_locations_attributes_0_name" name="post[locations_attributes][0][name]" type="hidden" value="Dresden">
        <input class="long" id="post_locations_attributes_0_longitude" name="post[locations_attributes][0][longitude]" type="hidden" value="13.7372621">
        <input class="lat" id="post_locations_attributes_0_latitude" name="post[locations_attributes][0][latitude]" type="hidden" value="51.0504088">

    </div>  
</div>
```

EDIT2:

*post.rb*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

require "acts-as-taggable-on"
require "kaminari"

acts_as_taggable    

self.table_name = "blog_posts"

self.paginates_per Blogit.configuration.posts_per_page

# ==============
# = Attributes =
# ==============
attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list, :blogger_id, :coverphoto, :locations_attributes



# ===============
# = Photo Model =
# ===============



    has_attached_file :coverphoto,
                :styles => {
                  :coverbar => "600x300>", :medium => "250x250^" , :thumb => "100x100^"},
                  #:source_file_options =>  {:all => '-rotate "-90>"'},
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                  :bucket => "backpackbug",
                  :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"                


# ===============
# = Validations =
# ===============

validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 66 }
validates :body,  presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
validates :blogger_id, presence: true



# =================
# = Associations =
# =================    

belongs_to :blogger, :polymorphic => true
has_many :location_post
has_many :locations, :through => :location_post
belongs_to :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }

end end
```

Comment: I don't see any `hidden_field`, can you post the view code where that field appears? Also, you appear to have two `end`s at the end of your `form_for` block, which I assume is just a copying mistake.

Comment: Hi @shioyama, Yes, the two 'ends' are a copying mistake, apologies. The hidden field is added by the 'nested form' gem i'm using and appears to be how it determines which one to delete. I've added a snippet of the rendered html above. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved with a combination of this and another answer, found here:

[How can I fix this create function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688896/how-can-i-fix-this-create-function/13689476#13689476)

A short term fix is to add attr_accessible :_destroy and attr_accessor :_destroy.

Thanks both!

Answer (score 0):

Add `:_destroy` to your `attr_accessible` list

```
attr_accessible ...., :_destroy
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for this however, I've tried this and still get the same error. It's not a table column so I don't think it should be trying to save a destroy attribute. Any other ideas?

Comment: @JamesOsborn to which model have you added attr_accessible :_destroy ?

Comment: Hi Pavel, I added this to post.rb and location.rb to no avail, i'm afraid. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should write to post.rb,

```
 attr_accessible: locations_atributes
```

and

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => true
```

as you are updating the location object via post object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Sorry, I didn't put up post.rb but it does contain this. I have now posted it up. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would rather suggest you to try all this with rails console and see whether the problem is really with the association or with view. Do check the web logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

replace `f.hidden_field` it must stay thus(line 2)

```
 module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    text_field_tag(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")
  end
```