# How can I fix this create function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function which splits nested attributes into an array so they can be checked for uniqueness and then saves them. The problem is, i'm getting a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _destroy` error because the `nested_form gem` inserts a hidden_field to highlight which attributes should be deleted.

Here's the *Posts_Contoller.rb* create function:

```
def create
   location_set = params[:post].delete(:locations_attributes) unless params[:post][:locations_attributes].blank?

   @post = current_blogger.blog_posts.new(params[:post])

   @post.locations = Location.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set) unless location_set.nil?


 if @post.save
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Blog post was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

Here's the function in *location.rb*:

```
def self.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set)
  #create a locations array
   locations = []
         locations = locations.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }

   location_set.each do |key, location|
       locations << find_or_initialize_by_name(location)
   end

 locations

 end
```

And here's the log:

```
 Started POST "/blog/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-03 17:31:54 +0000
 Processing by Blogit::PostsController#create as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r74iCzC4tJgVI6FiCEH7XzfiTmaqKihF5JSs7Ow3MSI=", "post"=>{"title"=>"This
 is a post about Paris", "body"=>"This is a post about ParisThis is a post about Paris
 This is a post about ParisThis is a post about Paris", "tag_list"=>"", 
 "locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"Paris", "longitude"=>"2.3522219", "latitude"=>"48.856614"}, "1354555760002"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"Los Angeles", "longitude"=>"-118.5155901", "latitude"=>"3
 4.03563310000001"}}}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "name"=>"losds", "legname"=>"Los Angeles",    "longitude"=>"-118.5155901", "latitud
 e"=>"34.03563310000001", "commit"=>"Submit"}

 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON  "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" W
 HERE "taggings"."taggable_id" IS NULL AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = 'Blogit::Post' AND  (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)

 Location Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."name" = 'Paris' LIMIT 1
 LOGGER LOCATIONS ARE[#<Location id: 768, name: "Paris", latitude: #<BigDecimal:7f86aadf6230,'0.48856614E2',18(45)>, longitude:
 #<BigDecimal:7f86aadf5f60,'0.23522219E1',18(45)>, post_id: nil, created_at: "2012-12-01 17:27:33", updated_at: "2012-12-01 17
 :27:33", notes: nil>]
 Location Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."name" = 'Los Angeles' LIMIT 1
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 97ms

  ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _destroy):
  app/models/location.rb:23:in `block in find_or_initialize_location_set'
  app/models/location.rb:21:in `each'
  app/models/location.rb:21:in `find_or_initialize_location_set'
  app/controllers/blogit/posts_controller.rb:79:in `create'
```

Any suggestions for how I can adapt this to include the delete function in the params as before but so I don't get the `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _destroy` error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
def self.find_or_initialize_location_set(location_set)
  #create a locations array
  locations = []
  locations = locations.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }

  location_set.each do |key, location|
    if location.delete(:_destroy) == "1"
      locations.delete_if {|elem| elem[:name] == location[:name]}
    else
      locations << find_or_initialize_by_name(location)   
    end
  end 

  locations 
end
```

Calling `delete` on the associated hash will modify the hash and return the value you're deleting (or `nil` if not present).

Or if you need the delete on the initialized location, you could do it there:

```
def find_or_initialize_by_name_with_delete(location)
  if location.delete(:_destroy)
    do_delete
  end

  find_or_initialize_by_name(location)
end
```

Comment: Hi Sean, Sorry, I just tested this and realised that this actually sends all attributes to the delete function. I need it to pick up something like `if location.attributes = {:_destroy => "1"}` any ideas?

Comment: Did you use `:_destroy` on delete?  I had `:delete` by mistake... see my edits.  When you call `delete` on a hash, it should modify the hash by deleting the key and return the deleted key.  So you could have `deleted_key = location.delete(:_destroy)`, and `:_destroy` would be removed from `location` and assigned to `deleted_key`.

Comment: Hi, yes, i noticed and changed it. The problem is all the attributes have a 'destroy' attribute but if it is to be removed then '_destroy' is set to 1. This is how it currently reads:

     `location_set.each do |key, location|
      if location.delete(:_destroy)
      locations.delete_if { |elem| elem = '"_destroy"=>"1"' }
      end`
I think it's picking up all the attributes as they all have destroy's. Any ideas?

Comment: Gotcha.  You could change it to `if location.delete(:_destroy) == "1"`.  I'm not sure I understand what you're doing with the next statement though.  What are you trying to do with `locations.delete_if {}`?

Comment: Ah, perfect, Thank you! That ensures only the ones I want to be deleted are detected. I'm trying to use `delete_if` to remove those elements marked `_destroy = 1` from the array. Any help with this would be incredibly appreciated too!

Comment: Okay, from my understanding, you are starting out with an empty array, correct?  So you shouldn't have anything in the array to delete.  In that case, you could do something like `locations << find_or_initialize_by_name(location) unless location.delete(:_destroy) == "1"`.  That will cause it to not be added to the array if `:_destroy` is equal to `"1"`.  It also has the added benefit is removing the `:_destroy` key from all of the locations, so as to not cause your original error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20581/discussion-between-sean-hill-and-james-osborn)

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of this error by adding this to your location model:

```
# NOT PERSISTENT
attr_accessor :_destroy
# ... 
attr_accessible :_destroy
```

Without this the `_destroy` attribute is protected against [mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) and when you try to assign values to it anyway an exception is thrown.

Comment: That's a dirty workaround, He should check the nested_form docs for solution

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I tried adding the above and got the following error `unknown attribute: _destroy`. It kind of feels like a messy work around, too. I would rather do it through some if function in the model if possible?

Comment: This solved the problem but the above answer was the one I used. Thanks!